# Have I implemented Equals()/GetHashCode() correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, gethashcode

The program was working with this implementation:

```
class Instrument
{
    public string ClassCode { get; set; }
    public string Ticker { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return " ClassCode: " + ClassCode + " Ticker: " + Ticker + '.';
    }
}
```

But because I need to use Instrument in Dictionary I've decided to implement equals/hashcode:

```
class Instrument
{
    public string ClassCode { get; set; }
    public string Ticker { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return " ClassCode: " + ClassCode + " Ticker: " + Ticker + '.';
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        Instrument instrument = obj as Instrument;
        if (instrument == null)
            return false;

        return ((ClassCode.Equals(instrument.ClassCode)) && (Ticker.Equals(instrument.Ticker));
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 13;
        hash = (hash * 7) + ClassCode.GetHashCode();
        hash = (hash * 7) + Ticker.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Now the program has stopped working. In such or similar places I receive "KeyNotFoundException":

```
if (cache.Keys.Any(instrument => instrument.Ticker == newTicker && instrument.ClassCode == newClassCode))
```

Is it possible that some pieces of the code assume that equals and hashcode IS NOT implemented?
Or probably I just implemented them wrong? Sorry I'm not familiar with such advanced features in C# as the last piece of code and don't know how it is connected with equals or hashCode.

Comment: Have a look at what Eric Lippert has to say on the matter - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx

In short your hash code should remain constant even if the instance mutates, so any implementation you do, should have this as the primary objective.

Comment: At the moment in time I'm on the go so I'll only throw in a link I found useful for the equals part... http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2010/02/28/138234.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your HashCode and Equals methods should depend only on *immutable* properties - your implementation uses ClassCode and Ticker which both have setters and are therefore mutable.

Comment: Thank you Joe, I didn't read why c# has so strange restrictions so far. I will read suggested articles tonight. However so far it sounds very very strange. If some object was equal to another, and then some property of one object was changed, I expect that objects not equals anymore! So "equals" must include all properties and especially mutable properties.... It's the way I do things in Java :)

Comment: @HuBeZa: imagine you put object into Dictionary, it will be assigned to bucket basing on its computed hash, say it goes to bucket #1. Now, you modify Ticker and/or ClassCode in object you've just put in and perform lookup with .Contains. Dictionary then calls GetHashCode to determine which bucket it should search for our object - and thanks to modified values, it assumes it's #2 instead of #1. It checks bucket #2 - your object is not there. Contains returns with false, on object you just put in dictionary. This is why you want immutable members for hash generation.

Comment: @jimmy_keen, excellent point. So I'm guessing that dictionary doesn't receive `OnPropertyChanged` notification for its keys, or something of that matter. So, the key hash is computed only when added. **I wonder why I never saw an article about that.**

Comment: @jimmy_keen I consider that as a valuable feature, not a danger :)

Answer (score 3):

**First**, instead of using `cache.Keys.Any` you can just use [ContainsKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4.aspx).

```
bool contains = cache.ContainsKey(
    new Instrument { Ticker = newTicker, ClassCode = newClassCode });
```

The first iterate over the whole keys list - O(n), while the second uses Dictionary's built in hash table implementation - O(1).

**Second**, check for null reference in your implementation:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
        return false;

    Instrument instrument = obj as Instrument;
    if (instrument == null)
        return false;

    // 1. string.Equals can handle null references.
    // 2. object.ReferenceEquals for better preformances when it's the same object
    return (object.ReferenceEquals(this, instrument)) ||
        (string.Equals(ClassCode, instrument.ClassCode) &&
        string.Equals(Ticker, instrument.Ticker));
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    int hash = 13;
    if (ClassCode != null)
        hash = (hash * 7) + ClassCode.GetHashCode();
    if (Ticker!= null)
        hash = (hash * 7) + Ticker.GetHashCode();

    return hash;
}
```

Other than that, I can't see a problem.

Comment: regarding "null" references, it's by design that my Instrument object can not contain "null" strings, so I would actually prefer to have NPE raised if some field is null accidentely. I think that codes uses cache.Keys.Any because equals and hashCode was not implemented (then ContainsKey will not work I suppose). The question is how is it possible to broke cache.Keys.Any implementing Equals/HashCode...

Answer (score 1):

> But because I need to use Instrument in Dictionary I've decided to implement equals/hashcode

That's the wrong reason. Your class already has implementations for Equality and GetHashCode that are suitable, efficient and tested for use in a Dictionary.

> Have I implemented Equals()/GetHashCode() correctly?

No. You are missing an overload for `==` to start with. And it will only be reliable when you make Instrument immutable.

#### Your best course of action is *not* to override any of those members.

Also see [this MSDN advice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28VS.80%29.aspx). Notice the "guarantees of Equals" and

> Overriding operator == in non-immutable types is not recommended.